# android - handler don't work in loop

Tags: android, android-os-handler

I want to do app to show 3 elements (each 2 seconds) and each start showing after the before element. Here is code:

```
public void gameStart()
{
    do
    {
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {

                if (data == 1)
                {
                    CountDownTimer cdt = new CountDownTimer(2000, 1000)
                    {

                        @Override
                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
                        {
                            element1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFinish()
                        {
                            element1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        }
                    }.start();

                } else if (data == 2)
                {
                    CountDownTimer cdt = new CountDownTimer(2000, 1000)
                    {

                        @Override
                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
                        {
                            element2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFinish()
                        {
                            element2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        }
                    }.start();

                } else if (data == 3)
                {
                    CountDownTimer cdt = new CountDownTimer(2000, 1000)
                    {

                        @Override
                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
                        {
                            element3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFinish()
                        {
                            element3.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        }
                    }.start();

                } else if (data == 4)
                {
                    CountDownTimer cdt = new CountDownTimer(2000, 1000)
                    {

                        @Override
                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
                        {
                            element4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFinish()
                        {
                            element4.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        }
                    }.start();

                } else if (data == 5)
                {
                    CountDownTimer cdt = new CountDownTimer(2000, 1000)
                    {

                        @Override
                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
                        {
                            element5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFinish()
                        {
                            element5.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        }
                    }.start();

                } else if (data == 6)
                {
                    CountDownTimer cdt = new CountDownTimer(2000, 1000)
                    {

                        @Override
                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
                        {
                            element6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFinish()
                        {
                            element6.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        }
                    }.start();

                }

                id = id + 1;
                text.setText("cos " + id);
                data = random.nextInt(6) + 1;
            }
        }, 2000);
    } while (id <= 3);

}
```

But if I start application, it start lagging. App shout down. What should I do?
And I also try this

```
public void gameStart()
{
    do
    {
                if (data == 1)
                {
                    element1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
                    {
                        public void run()
                        {
                            element1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }, 2000);

                } else if (data == 2)
                {
                    element2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
                    {
                        public void run()
                        {
                            element2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }, 2000);

                } else if (data == 3)
                {
                    element3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
                    {
                        public void run()
                        {
                            element3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }, 2000);

                } else if (data == 4)
                {
                    element4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
                    {
                        public void run()
                        {
                            element4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }, 2000);

                } else if (data == 5)
                {
                    element5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
                    {
                        public void run()
                        {
                            element5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }, 2000);

                } else if (data == 6)
                {
                    element6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
                    {
                        public void run()
                        {
                            element6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }, 2000);
                }

                id = id + 1;
                text.setText("cos " + id);
                data = random.nextInt(6) + 1;


    } while (id <= 3);

}
```

But all elements is visible in the same time

Comment: you call .each postDelayed with 2000 so the handler is executed  after two seconds

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to change? For instance, [this post shows how to use simple animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125936/android-change-picture-every-10-seconds) to change an `ImageView`

Comment: I try to do random omages which is show after before image

Comment: Ok, did you look at the answer I linked to? That should help. You are making it way more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: No it didn't help because I want show random images not my in order.

Comment: post one Runnable each time,  in that Runnable post it again and again

Comment: And app must remember which element was drawn

Comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14742120/randomly-change-background-image-in-android)

Comment: Okey I can do with 3 elements but if I want e.g. 50 elements?

Comment: this is good but I can't save which image was chosen

Comment: did you try posting ONE Runnable each time?

Comment: Yes I try but this good when I ude 3 elements but if I use 50 elements?

Comment: what's the difference? 3 or 50?

Comment: I want to do something which show elements and you must repeat and I want that this should be done while you make mistakes

Comment: And I don't know when you make mistakes. You can go to 1000 level or 100000 and elements must be show i this time

Comment: sorry i don't understand you at all

Comment: Okej thank you for help very much I will try. Sorry I want vote up but I haven't got reputation